# Informal word or rude

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, informal-language

Is there some rude or informal word if you want to sell broken thing to buyer without letting him know that it's broken?

Comment: foist? offload? fob off?

Comment: Used, worn, pre-owned, non-certified, as sold, as found  - and if you come from South Africa, "voetstoets".

Comment: Agree with @Apollyon on 'offload'. "Let's find some sap so we can offload these dodgy watches". 'Foist' can be a perfectly good item which is nonetheless unwanted: "She wouldn't stop foisting the teacakes on me". 'Fob off' can refer to a good item which is nonetheless less than was expected: "He fobbed me off with a £20 Sainsbury's voucher". I have a nagging feeling there is a better word, though. Is 'palm off' appropriate?

Comment: @legatrix, That's exactly what I looked for (palm off)

Comment: @Boyep That's good then!

Comment: If you want a noun, a **lemon** is slang for something for sale (most often a used car, but it could be something else) that is secretly defective or worthless.